# How to make a custom recurrent network in keras efficiently?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have a function that takes an (image , hidden state) as an input, and feedback the output back to the input, This goes for the length of the sequence and the last output is of interest to me :-

The recurrence function is as below:-

```
def recurrence():
input_image = Input(shape=[dim1,dim2,dim3])
hidden_state= Input(shape=[4,4,4,128])


conv1a = Conv2D(filters=96, kernel_size=7, padding='same',input_shape=(dim1, dim2,dim3), kernel_initializer=k_init, bias_initializer=b_init)(input_image)
conv1a = LeakyReLU(0.01)(conv1a)
conv1b = Conv2D(filters=96, kernel_size=3, padding='same', kernel_initializer=k_init, bias_initializer=b_init)(conv1a)
conv1b = LeakyReLU(0.01)(conv1b)
conv1b = ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1))(conv1b)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D(2)(conv1b)


flat6 = Flatten()(pool1)
fc7 = Dense(units=1024, kernel_initializer=k_init, bias_initializer=b_init)(flat6)
rect7 = LeakyReLU(0.01)(fc7)


t_x_s_update_conv = Conv3D(128, 3, activation=None, padding='same', kernel_initializer=k_init, use_bias=False)(hidden_state)
t_x_s_update_dense =Reshape((4,4,4,128))(Dense(units=8192)(rect7))

t_x_s_update = layers.add([t_x_s_update_conv, t_x_s_update_dense])


t_x_s_reset_conv = Conv3D(128, 3, activation=None, padding='same', kernel_initializer=k_init, use_bias=False)(hidden_state)
t_x_s_reset_dense =Reshape((4,4,4,128))(Dense(units=8192)(rect7))
t_x_s_reset =layers.add([t_x_s_reset_conv, t_x_s_reset_dense])


update_gate = Activation(K.sigmoid)(t_x_s_update)
comp_update_gate = Lambda(lambda x: 1 - x)(update_gate)
reset_gate = Activation(K.sigmoid)(t_x_s_reset)


rs = layers.multiply([reset_gate, hidden_state])
t_x_rs_conv = Conv3D(128, 3, activation=None, padding='same', kernel_initializer=k_init, use_bias=False)(rs)
t_x_rs_dense = Reshape((4,4,4,128))(Dense(units=8192)(rect7))
t_x_rs = layers.add([t_x_rs_conv, t_x_rs_dense])


tanh_t_x_rs = Activation(K.tanh)(t_x_rs)


gru_out = layers.add([layers.multiply([update_gate, hidden_state]), layers.multiply([comp_update_gate, tanh_t_x_rs])])


return Model(inputs=[input_image,hidden_state],outputs=gru_out)
```

Currently i am achieving this using a loop and instantiating a model once and then reusing it like below:-

```
step=recurrence()


s_update = hidden_init
for i in input_imgs:
    s_update = step([i, s_update])`
```

But this method seems to be suffer from the following two disadvantages:

i) It consumes a lot of GPU memory considering all variables are shared.

ii) It doesn't work for an arbitrary length sequence without padding.

Is there a better and efficient way to achieve this , I tried reading the code for SimpleRNN in the recurrent.py file , but couldn't understand how would i incorporate all these layers like Convolution3d into that framework?
A dummy code would be really appreciated or any help you could provide.  Thanks !